# how to speed up execution on aspx pages with large amount of data into gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, viewstate, page-lifecycle

I'm developing an Asp.net web application.

In that application i need to show a report with three grid-views on a form with a large amount of data.Paging is enabled on all grids.

When user views report first 3-5 times it works fine but after that it takes a lot of time in loading.

I'm storing `grid-views` data into view state so that i can use this data at paging and sorting.

Can any one tell me what is the problem and how can i solve that problem

Comment: share some code. Especially the queries, and GC (disposes) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do following to make it faster.

1. Paging : Do custom paging instead of standard paging so only page-size amount of data is stored for the current page. It will hugely improve the performance. Please refer [**Custom Paging.**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/410733/Custom-paging-with-ASP-NET-GridView)
2. Also in the page, disable the view-state of controls if not required.
3. You can also use caching if grid-view data is read-only. [**Caching**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.aspx)

Comment: +1 for ViewState disabling, this is toxic if you use GridView.

Comment: better reference for *Custom Paging* ? not spaguetti code, using 3 layers, and `List<T>`

Comment: Be very careful using that first example (1.) It grabs the page index from a query string parameter and does not pass it as a parameter to the SQL statement. This is crying out for sql injection. Should always use AddWithValue (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It´s difficult to resolve performance problems without having all information about your code and server.

Can be a concurrence problem?

Are you doing another operations in the web page that reduce performance?

Is your webpage alone in the server or are there other apps that can interfere with yours?

I expect give you some clue.